# disable angular ng-select window

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

We are using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) in a project and I'm facing the problem that I can't disable the ng-select window. Is it possible to disable it with native code or do I need to find some custom solution?

```
  <ng-select 
    #changeowner
    class="custom-owner"
    [placeholder]="leagueOwner.full_name"
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    [clearable]="false"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    (scrollToEnd)="onAdminLoadScrollEnd()"
    bindLabel="full_name">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: [disabled]="true"  use property binding to disable

Comment: @Chellappan that's because you need a formControlName option set as stated here : https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/132

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As stated in other responses you can use the option

```
[disabled]="booleanValue"
```

However you will need a formControlName value set as well as described [here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/132).

You would get:

```
<!-- test-component.html -->
<ng-select [disabled]="myDisabledCondition" formControlName="myFormControl" 
...>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: @Bogdan Tushevskyi You have accepted this answer so does it really work in reactive form?

Comment: make sure you have ngModel attribute. Ex. `<ng-select [(ngModel)]=".." [disabled]="..."></ngselect>` Otherwise angular will complain that `disabled` cannot be used.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the Angular reactive form and trying to disable the **ng-select** using the following code then sorry it will not work in some case. If you are using **formControlName** then it will not work but work in **[(ngModel)]** case.

`[disabled] = true`

The best way to do this is by using reactive form control.

```
this.createReactiveform.controls['some_key'].disable(true);
```

Answer (score 13):

With latest angular versions `disabled` attribute doesn't live well with `formControlName`.
One way to disable `ng-select` with `formControlName` is to show `readonly` textbox instead of disabled dropdown:

```
<div *ngIf="!disabledCondition">
  <ng-select 
    #changeowner
    formControlName="owner"
    class="custom-owner"
    [placeholder]="leagueOwner.full_name"
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    [clearable]="false"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    (scrollToEnd)="onAdminLoadScrollEnd()"
    bindLabel="full_name">
  </ng-select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="disabledCondition">      
  <input formControlName="owner" class="form-control" type="text" readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using reactForms, the correct way to disable inputs is to use:

```
 formGroup.get('controlName').disable()
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [readonly] input

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#api

```
[readonly]  boolean     false   no  Set ng-select as readonly. Mostly used with reactive forms.
```

Comment: That is worked for me. [disabled] did not work after the variable got updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use `[disabled]="true"`

```
<ng-select 
    [disabled]="true"
    #changeowner
    class="custom-owner"
    [placeholder]="leagueOwner.full_name"
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    [clearable]="false"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    (scrollToEnd)="onAdminLoadScrollEnd()"
    bindLabel="full_name">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: i have this template parse error on this: Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'

Answer (score 3):

If you are using reactiveForms, the correct way to disable inputs is to use:

```
 formGroup.get('controlName').disable()
```

in case you need to empty the formcontrol

```
 formGroup.get('controlName').setValue("");
```

Answer (score 3):

adding [disabled]="true" did not work for me
But setting [readOnly] to true did. Based on documentation that is a way to go with reactive forms:

[readonly]  boolean false   no  Set ng-select as readonly. Mostly used with reactive forms.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-select` has native method which not include in official documentation - 
`setDisabledState(boolean)`
So, i used

```
@ViewChild ('changeowner') changeOwnerRef: ElementRef;
```

and can use this method like this:

```
(<any>this.changeOwnerRef).setDisabledState(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use disable attribute:

```
<ng-select 
   [disabled]="true">
</ng-select>
```

If you get `Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-select'.` You have to reference `FormsModule`:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [FormsModule, NgSelectModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Angular (e.g., version 13), the [disabled] attribute may not work correctly with the  component. To disable the  component in Angular version 13, you can use an alternative approach.

First, create a CSS class that disables the pointer-events:

```
.ng-select-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Next, in your component or template file, apply this class based on the value of the readOnly variable for example:

```
<ng-select 
    #changeowner
    class="custom-owner"
    [placeholder]="leagueOwner.full_name"
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    [clearable]="false"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    (scrollToEnd)="onAdminLoadScrollEnd()"
    bindLabel="full_name"
    [class.ng-select-disabled]="readOnly" <!-- Bind to the readOnly variable -->
    >
</ng-select>
```